# Single quotes in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, quotes

I have created my table dynamically and in one of my td's I have function where I'm passing two different parameters. One of them is ID and does not need quotes around but second parameter need single quotes and I tried so many combinations like "e; or \' and I could not get what I need. Here is my code:

```
tbl +="<td><a onClick='DeleteRes(slotsPtc,"+jsData[key].res_ID+")'></a></td>
```

Code above gave me this:

```
<a onclick="DeleteRes(slotsPtc,327)"></a>
```

I'm missing single quotes around first parameter `slotsPtc` if anyone can help how I can put single quotes around that parameter please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&apos;` (or `&#39;`) as a single quote in HTML:

```
tbl += "<td><a onClick='DeleteRes(&apos;slotsPtc&apos;,"+jsData[key].res_ID+")'></a></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert quotes in a string by escaping them with a `\` character. I recommend using escaped double quotes for your onclick attribute value and then you can use single quotes without escaping:

```
tbl +="<td><a onClick=\"DeleteRes('slotsPtc',"+jsData[key].res_ID+")\"></a></td>
```